# Skip strings when performing .sum() operation using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, naivebayes

I have started implementing Multinomial Naive Bayes with the following dataframe:

```
   Disc Bus Dep Edu
0   1   2   2   1   
1   0   1   1   1   
2   1   2   1   4   
3   0   1   1   1   
4   0   2   1   3
```

I have also divided it into train/test

`X = data_rev.drop('Disc', axis = 1)`

`y = data_rev['Disc']`

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 21)`

I then start calculating the probabilities:
1. Calculate prior log probability for each class (Use np.unique to return the sorted unique elements of an array)

`separated = [[x for x, t in zip(X_train, y_train) if t == c] for c in np.unique(y_train)]`

`count_sample = X_train.shape[0]`

`self.class_log_prior_ = [np.log(len(i) / count_sample) for i in separated]`

2. Count each occurrence for each class

`count = np.array([np.array(i).sum(axis = 0) for i in separated])`

But somehow it throws me an error saying `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`. Apparently, when passing `axis = 0`, numpy detects a string (dataframe headers) and it cannot perform the operation. Is that what is going on? How can I fix this within this `count` operation?

Step 3 is the following:

`feature_log_prob_ = np.log(count / count.sum(axis = 1)[np.newaxis].T)` which of course is throwing an error because it's calling `count`.

Comment: With your sample and code, `separated` is: `[['Dep'], ['Bus', 'Edu']]`.  Doing `sum` those sublists of strings will produce your error.  May I suggest showing the intermediate results of your calculation, not just the initial dataframe.  That we can all see (without having to run your code) what is happening.

Comment: If I use `X = data_rev.drop('Disc', axis = 1).to_numpy()` (and same for `Y`), `count`runs.  Applying numpy functions directly to dataframe objects is not a great idea.  Sometimes it work, but not predictably.